# FS.Collection Image ID don't validate check()

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to save image id after insert in FS.Collection.

#### Insert array

```
var item = {
    name: $(value).find('#name').val(),
    article: $(value).find('#article').val(),
    description: $(value).find('#description').val(),
    price: $(value).find('#price').val(),
    sizes: $(value).find('#sizes').val()
};
file = $(value).find('#attachmentName')[0].files[0];
if (file !== undefined) {
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        item = _.extend(item, {
            image: fileObj._id.toString()
        });
    });
}
Meteor.call('collectionInsert', item, function(error, result) {
    if (error)
        return alert(error.reason);
    Router.go('collection', {_id: result._id});
});
```

#### collectionInsert method

```
Meteor.methods({
collectionInsert: function(postAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(postAttributes, {
        name: String,
        article: String,
        description: String,
        price: String,
        sizes: String,
        image: String
    });
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
        userId: user._id,
        author: user.profile.name,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        views: 0
    });
    var collectionId = Collections.insert(post);
    return {
        _id: collectionId
    };
}
});
```

Then i'm got Exception

```
Exception while invoking method 'collectionInsert' Error: Match error: Missing key 'image'
```

In console log i have item value

```
...
image: "4J55dyGb5DpqbCXGG"
...
```

I'm trying to change check property to <kbd>image: Match.Optional([String])</kbd> and <kbd>image: Match.Any</kbd> - no effect

Comment: If you console.log the post variable, what is the output ?

Comment: Item array without image key

Comment: The check function checks if the image field is present, it's not and that's why that error occures

Comment: Can i get checks after Images.insert()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your insert method is non-blocking, which means that you probably haven't received the `fileObj` nor extended `item` before passing it to the method call. Maybe you should try to make the method call in the insert callback, like this:

```
if (file !== undefined) {
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        item.image = fileObj._id.toString(); // don't need _.extend

        // item should now be extended
        Meteor.call('collectionInsert', item, function(error, result) {
            if (error)
                return alert(error.reason);
            Router.go('collection', {_id: result._id});
        });
    });
}
```

By the way, you should probably store the result of `$(value)` instead of constructing the same jQuery object over and over. Just a minor optimization, but improves readability nonetheless.

```
var $value = $(value);
var item = {
    name: $value.find('#name').val(),
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes it's works, but if user don't select an image insert not occur.

Comment: Well that's the point, right? You're checking to see if file is defined before inserting, and on the server, you also use check in the method to make sure image exists.